# How to stop a while loop in correct place?

Tags: java, loops, arraylist, while-loop, char

I need help because I can't stop the while loop in the correct place.
On this example, I want to remove the last char as long as the String "seq" will be the same as some number on the list (867), then stop.

More advanced is, after finding the String, to add them to new ArrayList, then try to find the rest of String (75). If found, also input to new Array.

All better solutions are very welcome. Thanks!

The ArrayList list can contain hundreds of elements, there are 4 only, some elements in the list can repeat more than one time. Find first on the list is fine for me at this moment. If found, split 86775 to 867:75. Remove 867 from String seq and add to new ArrayList. Finally, we have to find 75 - if it doesn't exist, split to 7:5, and try to find 7 and 5. On my list, single numbers always exist so no problem with exceptions.

If you want to use split method always I need to find the higher number as possible, then if not found split and removing last one but I need every digit.

The String being examined can have 20 chars or more. This is the simplest example possible.

I was looking for many methods to solve this problem and I am not sure this is best.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("567");
        list.add("867");
        list.add("86");
        list.add("75");
        System.out.println(list);
        String seq = "86775";
        System.out.println(seq + ": found ?: " + getPatternFound(String.valueOf(list), seq) + " times");
        int nbChar = 0;
        do {
            getRemoveLastChar(seq, 1);
            if (getPatternFound(String.valueOf(list), seq) == 0) ;
            getRemoveLastChar(seq, 2);
            nbChar++;
            System.out.println(getRemoveLastChar(seq, nbChar));

        }
        while (nbChar < seq.length());

    }

    private static String getRemoveLastChar(String str, int nbChar) {
        return str.substring(0, str.length() - nbChar);
    }

    private static int getPatternFound(String longString, String pat) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(pat);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(longString);
        int count = 0;
        while (matcher.find())
            count++;
        return count;
    }
}
```

```
[567, 867, 86, 30]
867755: found ?: 0 times
86775
8677
867 <- stop here
86
8
```

Comment: if you do want to stop a while then you always can use a flag, some boolean that will be false when you want to stop the while

Comment: please give a more detailed example, which variable contains which value, why do you want to continue or stop, whats the input and the expected output

Comment: @vmrvictor The input in already there in the code. It's just the output as shown is not formatted correctly.

Comment: sorry I cannot understand what do you expect and what is not correct in the output

Comment: If I understand this Question correctly, the `getPatternFound(String.valueOf(list), seq)` is suppose to return how many times a value (represented as a String) in the list is matched on the `seq`. While it returns 0, the loop continues. So `getPatternFound` isn't correctly implemented.

Comment: Hi I was extended my question, I hope is more clear right now.

Comment: getPatternFound(String.valueOf(list), seq) is only telling me is exist (if>0). 0 means, not found and we have to remove last char from string and try to find new shorter String again on Array. If found we have to remember also about removing char is also important.

Comment: You can use the break command to exit the while loop at any time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the main question: how do you quit when done?

Of course you can do it in-loop with the `break` or `continue` keywords.
What I deem more elegant is the use of `return` in a separate method.
It makes the code easier to understand if later you have changes.

Here is an implementation that shows the behaviour as you stated:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("567");
        list.add("867");
        list.add("86");
        list.add("75");
        System.out.println("List = " + list);
        String seq = "86775";

        String result = search(list, seq);

    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param list
     * @param seq
     * @return null means no match;
     */
    private static String search(ArrayList<String> list, String seq) {
        while (seq.length() > 0) {
            System.out.println("analyzing seq: " + seq);

            boolean broken = false;
            for (String s : list) {
                if (seq.contentEquals(s)) { // if matched

                    System.out.println("found match: " + s);
                    // do your logic, for example
                    seq = seq.replace(s, "");

                    // quit the loop at right place
                    return s;
                }
            }
            seq = seq.substring(0, seq.length() - 1);

        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

generates output:

```
List = [567, 867, 86, 75]
analyzing seq: 86775
analyzing seq: 8677
analyzing seq: 867
found match: 867
```

When reading what you want to do with it: the String API offers `String.contains(String infix)` in combination with `String.replace(String old, String new)` . These should solve your real problem much better than doing everything manually in loops.

Comment: Hmm. I think `String.contains()`might do a lot of good for you. Make a loop where you iterate over all elements of your list and check, whether `seq` contains that element, if yes, act upon it, if no, let the loop run out.

Or you can play with `String.indexOf( another_String)` and `String.replaceFirst(regex, replacement)`